# combinaison between datatable values using C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, datatable

I want to declare mathematical expression between values from datatable, for example: I have two columns named `Variable`(string) and `Contents` (float), I have inserted in `Variables` 3 string `a`, `b` and `c` and in `Contents` 3 floats are `0`, `3` and `6`. Now I want to declare `a = b + c` in code an when I click on a 'button' the variable a will change in datatable to 9. Here is my code but it doesn't work!! I mean after I run no errors occurred but no changes happened in datatable `a = '0'`!

```
private void Modify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from TableVar ";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(dt);
    DataRow dr1 = dt.Select("Variable='a'").FirstOrDefault();
    DataRow dr2 = dt.Select("Variable='b'").FirstOrDefault();
    DataRow dr3 = dt.Select("Variable='c'").FirstOrDefault();

    dr1["Contents"] = Convert.ToDouble(dr2["Contents"])+ Convert.ToDouble(dr3["Contents"]);
    con.Close();
}
```

Yes, I tried that method despite that I need to call variables `a`, `b` and `c` but I tried to do this code with their positions 0,1 and 2, but an error is displayed

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The dynamic SQL generation of
>   UpdateCommand is not supported for a SelectCommand that does not
>   return key column information.'

So what is primarykey? I'm newb! :(

```
  con.Open();
  string query = "SELECT Contents FROM Taom ";
  System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
  SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
  sqlDa.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
  SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlDa);
  sqlDa.Fill(dt);

  dt.Rows[0]["Contents"] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[1]["Contents"]).ToString() + Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[2]["Contents"]).ToString();
  sqlDa.UpdateCommand = cb.GetUpdateCommand();
  sqlDa.Update(dt);
  con.Close();
```

this is a picture of my simple datatable i just want to run my code then 'a' will change to 9 ! that's all !
[image: Datatable]

Comment: Your `SqlDataAdapter` needs an `UpdateCommand` and you need to call its `Update` method to change the database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters

Comment: @Crowcoder Can you look at my edited answer please :)

Comment: Select the table's primary key along with Content. That is what the error is telling you.

Comment: @Crowcoder yes i know but i didn't understand what that mean i google it and i tried to solve that error but i fail !

Comment: Do you know what a primary key is? When you make an update you always have to add a `WHERE` clause unless you actually want to update every row in a table. Usually it is `UPDATE <table> SET <whatever> = <whatever> WHERE <the primary key> = <whatever>`. A data adapter must have the primary key information so it can figure out what to update.

Comment: @Crowcoder  the primary key is Contents but what's the condition here !

Comment: I don't think `Contents` is your primary key. If it is then you can't update it anyway. Based on the data in that column you are very likely to get duplicate values which would be a key violation.

Comment: @Crowcoder So what i have to do i'm powerless!!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know the schema of your database and I don't know what `GetUpdateCommand()` is doing. [This is a sample project](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid/tree/master/CSharpCrudGrid) I created to demonstrate using data adapters. It uses sqlite but don't let that distract you from how the adapter and commands are setup. You will have to figure out what your primary key is which should just require a quick look at the table in the database.

Comment: @Crowcoder Your code make changes only in DataGridView  , i'm searching how to update datatable ! but thank you anyway :) i'll edit my answer to show you the schema of my database!